# Can gRPC server stream return a Stream to Blazor Wasm instead of IAsyncEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, blazor, grpc, filestream, .net-6.0

I need to stream a file from ASP.NET Core to Blazor WASM using gRPC.

I would like to use the new class `DotNetStreamReference` added in net6 to allow stream directly to disk using `JSInterop` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Now, the problem is: gRPC method stream data returning a `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, but the `DotNetStreamReference` class accept only a `Stream` object as input.

There is a way to convert `IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>` to a `Stream` or eventually return a `Stream` from a gRPC call?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this without modifying Grpc's code, but you might be lucky with some low-level hackery with custom serializers and deserializers https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/143d1a7e2cb188f6de9c37e39fe04576197b41cd/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/Marshaller.cs#L121 and custom grpc method handlers. Overall, this is experts-only area and I'd recommend against doing that since the performance improvements aren't going to be worth the extra complexity (unless you've done extensive analysis before and it's THE bottleneck of your app).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the gRPC part, but for the 'convert' question, definitely:

```
var streamContent = new byte[] {};
await foreach(var chunk in your_iasyncenumerable)
{
    streamContent.Concat(chunk);
}
```

Comment: loop and create a byte array is not my goal, i need to stream the file to disk to preserve the memory allocation.

Comment: You mean you want to stream the file to a `FileStream` rather than a `MemoryStream`